# Spring MVC - отображение ссылок

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте, у меня есть задача принять через GET запрос, ссылку вот по такому шаблону =

```
GET http://localhost/<url>
```

Вот мой контроллер -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{link} ", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void addLink(@PathVariable("link") String link) {
        System.out.print(link);
    }
```

Если перейти по ссылке

```
http://localhost:8080/google.com
```

то все работает корректно, а если добавить слэш, то контроллер не отрабатывает

```
http://localhost:8080/google.com/saa
```

Comment: Надо эскейпить служебные символы. Методы URL encode / decode есть в любом ЯП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{link}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

Контроллер не отрабатывает, потому что ссылка не совпадает с путем, на который он прицеплен.

Если нужно передавать ссылку, обычно это делают параметром GET-запроса:

```
/saa?link='https://google.com/'
```

Почему не устраивает такой вариант?

Comment: Я знаю, что так можно но задание было другим